# ImportError: No module named 'ipdb'

Tags: python, ipdb

I'm new to python and I'm trying to use the interactive python debugger in the standard python package.  Whenever I run "import ipdb" in my text editor (atom) or in the command line through iPython then I get the error:
ImportError: No module named 'ipdb'

Where is my ipdb module? It's still missing after I reinstalled python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

`pdb` is built-in.  `ipdb` you will have to install.

```
pip install ipdb
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks Wim!!

Answer (score 12):

`ipdb` comes with `ipython`, so if you already have `ipython` installed you can access it through that package using the following:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb
ipdb = Pdb()
```

Then you can use ipdb just as though you had done `import ipdb`, such as:

```
ipdb.runcall(self, func, *args, **kwds)
ipdb.run(self, cmd, globals=None, locals=None)
# etc.
```

If you don't have `ipython` installed, then you can just use `pdb` which is the built-in debugger. The main difference is `ipdb` has some extra bells and whistles.

Answer (score 3):

In the specific case that you want a more featureful `ipdb` debugger (including things like autocomplete), `ipython` also has one built-in (from what I can tell it's actually the one that `ipython` uses by default). Specifically, you can instead run

```py
from IPython.terminal.debugger import TerminalPdb
ipdb = TerminalPdb()
```

and get the same features as the commands from @Scott H's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47082108/13395519), but now you get autocomplete in the debugger that comes up!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed using `--user` argument. You can check the executable name in `~/.local/bin`. It's probably named `ipdb3`

```sh
$ ipdb
-bash: ipdb: command not found

$ ipdb3
usage: python -m ipdb [-c command] ... pyfile [arg] ...

Debug the Python program given by pyfile.
```